# is there a way to display a html ( rendered by a jsp) in angular?

Tags: angular, jsp

We have a very big application which is built on simple JSP/Servlets(more than 200 jsp's). Communication between model and view is through request parameters mostly.
We want to migrate this application to Angular but we are not ready to rebuild the whole app immediately.

So the idea is to build an Angular with same menu structure as previous Legacy application. On-click on each menu should basically renders the same html rendered by the JSP for now.
Later we can start migrating module by module with Angular components and Rest API for the data part.

So i want to know if there is a way the render the html returned by a remote server directly in Angular?
Any hint on how to start will help.

Thanks

Comment: Assuming you don't have CORS problems you can use the angular `sanitizer` to load the html in a block (such as a div) o directly into an iFrame. https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer

Comment: The basic functionalty of using Angular itself is rendering components by modifying DOM structure. Why in the first place you want to display a HTML already rendered by JSP in Angular? If it is already rendered outside Angular's context, you won't be able to use any of the features it provides.

Comment: What about using an iframe? it might work for pure displaying  the html generated by the JSPs... you should investigate for the interaction between iframes and your app...